# Is it possible to use JavaScript and JQuery at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, document-ready

Question provoked as **I wondered if I can just declare `$(document).ready()` at the top of `<script>` and write regular vanilla JS inside of it so that I don't have to declare `$(document).ready()` everytime I use JQuery.**

I also tested if JQuery can be used with JS locally (inside of '{}'). But it seems like below code doesn't work.

Can someone clarify on this please? Thank you.

```
<style>

#demoDiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px brown solid;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='demoDiv'></div>
<br>
<button id='testButton' onclick='testFunc()'>Test</button>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

function testFunc() {
    $('#demoDiv').style.display = 'none';
}

});


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: PS, you should use the console to inspect your errors (`$('#demoDiv').style`). And you don't need DOM ready if you place (like you did) `<script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag. Also, avoid the use of inline JS `onclick='testFunc()'` use `Element.addEventListener()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is a JavaScript library, so you can use jQuery with any other JavaScript functions.

Your particular example doesn't work for two reasons.

---

First, because `.style` is a property of DOM objects and not jQuery objects.

You could extract a DOM object from the jQuery object:

```
$('#demoDiv')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Or just consistently use the jQuery API:

```
$('#demoDiv').css("display", "none");
```

---

Second, because `testFunc` is not a global so is out of scope for your inline event handler.

Use `$('#testButton').on('click', testFunc)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You always use vanilla JS when you use jQuery. The thing is, jQuery is written in JavaScript.

Even the essence of jQuery, `$`, is vanilla JavaScript function under the hood.